# Should I use HTML::Parser or XML::Parser to extract and replace text?

Tags: html, xml, perl, parsing

I am looking at being able to extract all plain text and analyse/amend from HTML/XHTML document and then replace if needed. Can I do this using [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::Parser) or should it be [XML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/XML::Parser)?

Are there any good demonstrations that anyone knows of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also look at  [Web::Scraper](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/Web-Scraper/Web/Scraper.html).
I find this module easier than the HTML::Parser modules, but it helps if your are familiar with XPath.
Parsing of HTML is very unpredictable depending on the actual pages - it is like pdf-display and not data-oriented.

Answer (score 4):

The approach of HTML::Parser is based on tokens and callbacks. I find it very convenient when you have particularly complex conditions on the context in which the data you whish to extract or to change occurs.

Otherwise I prefer a tree based approach. [HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=html%3A%3Atreebuilder&mode=all) (based ultimely on HTML::Parser) allows you to find nodes with XPath. It returns [HTML::Element](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=html%3A%3Aelement&mode=all)s. The documentation is a little scarce (well, spread over a couple of modules). But still the quick way to mine into HTML.

If you deal with pure XML, [XML::Twig](http://xmltwig.com/) is an outstanding parser: very good memory management, allows to combine the tree and stream approaches. And the documentation is very good.

Answer (score 4):

Say in someone's StackOverflow user page you want to replace all instances of PERL with Perl. You could do so with

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use HTML::Parser;
use LWP::Simple;

my $html = get "http://stackoverflow.com/users/201469/phil-jackson";
die "$0: get failed" unless defined $html;

sub replace_text {
  my($skipped,$markup) = @_;
  $skipped =~ s/\bPERL\b/Perl/g;
  print $skipped, $markup;
}

my $p = HTML::Parser->new(
  api_version => 3,
  marked_sections => 1,
  case_sensitive => 1,
  unbroken_text => 1,
  xml_mode => 1,
  start_h => [ \&replace_text => "skipped_text, text" ],
  end_h => [ \&replace_text => "skipped_text, text" ],
);

# your page may use a different encoding
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8" or die "$0: binmode: $!";
$p->parse($html);
```

The output is what we expect:

```
$ wget -O phil-jackson.html http://stackoverflow.com/users/201469
$ ./replace-text >out.html
$ diff -ub phil-jackson.html out.html
--- phil-jackson.html
+++ out.html
@@ -327,7 +327,7 @@

 PERL:  

-#$linkTrue =  &hellip; ">comparing PERL md5() and PHP md5()</a></h3>
+#$linkTrue =  &hellip; ">comparing Perl md5() and PHP md5()</a></h3>

         <div class="tags t-php t-perl t-md5">
             <a href="/questions/tagged/php" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'php'" rel="tag">php</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/perl" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'perl'" rel="tag">perl</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/md5" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged 'md5'" rel="tag">md5</a>
```

The "PERL:" sore thumb is part of an element attribute, not a text section.

Answer (score 1):

Which module you should use depends on what you are trying to do. For starters, [HTML::Parser](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser) comes with great examples which also include a script that extracts plain text from an HTML document.

Do not try to parse HTML documents using an XML parser: You will find yourself in a world of pain as a lot of valid HTML constructs are not valid XML.

Do not try to parse XML documents using an HTML parser: You will lose all the advantages of the stricter requirement that an XML document be well formed before it can be parsed.